# Run method not getting called in Thread

Tags: java, android, xml, multithreading

I am trying to parse xml using a seperate thread. The small code snippet of the entire code is as below:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           try{
            c=c1;
            URL url = new URL(url1);
            HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream i= con.getInputStream();
            xf=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            xp=xf.newPullParser();
            xp.setInput(i,null);
            parseXML(xp,c);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        }
    });
    t.start();
```

But it seems the run method is not getting called itself. Can someone please help e find out what am I missing here.

EDIT:
Following is the whole code related to XML:

```
public void fetchXml(String u,final Context c1) throws IOException,   XmlPullParserException, InterruptedException {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           try{

            c=c1;
               URL url = new URL(url1);
            HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream i= con.getInputStream();
            xf=XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            xp=xf.newPullParser();
            xp.setInput(i,null);
            parseXML(xp,c);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
     }
    });

    t.start();
    t.join();
   }


  public void parseXML(XmlPullParser xp,Context c) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

    int event;
    String text=null;
    Toast.makeText(c, "inside parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    event=xp.getEventType();

    while(event!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
    {

        String name=xp.getName();

        switch(event)
        {

            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG :
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.TEXT :
                text=xp.getText();
                break;

            case XmlPullParser.END_TAG :
                if(name.equals("country")){
                    country=text;
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Country"+country, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if(name.equals("humidity")){

                    humidity=xp.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                    Toast.makeText(c, "humidity"+humidity,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                else if (name.equals("pressure"))
                {
                    pressure=xp.getAttributeValue(null,"value");
                    Toast.makeText(c, "pressure"+pressure,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{}
                break;
   }
        event=xp.next();
  }
    parsingcomplete=true;
  }
```

Also when I checked the logcat I am getting the following error for the Toast statement I wrote in inside the parsexml function above.

```
 04-11 07:59:08.891 31361-31580/com.example.hp.xmlparsing W/System.err:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not  called Looper.prepare()
 04-11 07:59:08.892 31361-31580/com.example.hp.xmlparsing W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
```

It looks like the run method is running fine..but I am getting the exception :

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not    called Looper.prepare()
```

Can someone please help...

Comment: What makes you think it's not getting called?

Comment: Add `t.join()` after `t.start()`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch just curious how will t.join() make a diffrence?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch still no success..

Comment: @Jois My assumption was the program terminated before the thread could start.

Comment: @ghostrider can post your full code

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It can't unless that thread is a daemon thread.

Comment: You can't use `Toast` outside main(GUI) thread.

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
Toast.makeText(c, "inside parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

inside GUI Thread:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                         Toast.makeText(c, "inside parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: thanks for the above..I am able to show the toast on UI thread..But now I am getting an exception:   

     Java.lang.RuntimeException : Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()